# Cassandra nodes can not talk to each other

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra

I've installed cassandra on 3 AWS EC2 instances but none of them can ping each other neither do telnet on 7000.

`telnet tm1 7000
Trying 172.31.30.37...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out`

Below is the output for netstat

`netstat -na|grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN`

I understand for cassandra inter node communication i need to have 7000 port open but wondering how can i make it listen on ubuntu.

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: are you certain cassandra is running? `nodetool info` work? netstat should show more than ssh listening if cassandra was running.

Answer (score 3):

Ok so you're testing TCP communication for port `7000` here, but this could be any port really. The first thing you need to do is setup a process to listen on a port and then test the connection (a TCP socket must first be opened before you can test connectivity to it).

You can use `netcat` (`nc`) which is an ideal tool to check this. Ensure you have it installed first then you can run up a "server" to bind to a port like so:

```
nc -l 0.0.0.0 7000
```

Then you can check to make sure its listening

```
$ netstat -lnt | awk '/7000/;NR==2'
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Finally check connectivity from your other node like so:

```
$ nc -v -w2 10.1.2.3 7000
Connection to 10.1.2.3 7000 port [tcp/afs3-bos] succeeded!
```

*The `-v`is for verbose and the `-w` is a timeout*

Note outside of testing ports, ping is not going to be a good test for general connectivity because in a lot of cases ICMP packets are dropped (security). So if it doesn't ping, it doesn't mean you have a connection issue.